Communication problems with pySerial over RS-232
I want to use pySerial to communicate with an Agilent 33250A using the built in RS-232 port. I went through the RS-232 configuration in the user manual and wrote the following code, which should set the right configuration to serial.Serial if I am not mistaken (in the instrument I have baud rate 9600, parity bits None/8 Bits, and hand-shake DTR):
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    timeout = 1,
    dsrdtr = True,
)

ser.write(b'*IDN?')
s = ser.read(99)
print(s)

This always prints b'' because of the timeout=1, when it should print something like b'Agilent Technologies,33250A,0,m.mm-l.ll-f.ff-gg-p'. If instead I send the command ser.write(b'APPL:SIN 5 KHZ, 3.0 VPP, -2.5 V') I would expect the device to change its settings (see here), but nothing happens. Every time I send anything using ser.write(b'...'), the instrument automatically switches to remote mode, so it receives something.
What am I missing? The only setting I don't see how to change in pySerial is the "number of start bits", which for my device is 1.

I found the problem, I was missing a \n at the end of each command. I did not find this in the manual, I just tried and now it works. So the complete code now is this:
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    timeout = 1,
    dsrdtr = True,
)

ser.write(b'*IDN?\n')
s = ser.read(99)
print(s)

